# Spring accessing keystore file

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I currently have a Spring server with Maven that stores a KeyStore file with users private keys in `src/main/java/com.resource` package. The problem is that when a maven update is performed the keystore file is reset so all the private keys are lost. I started doing research on where a keystore file should be placed and found [Apaches documentation on handling keystore files](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) but how would I access that file from the servlet code when needing to put or get a key? Because it isn't in Tomcat's scope.

Is this the correct convention when dealing with keystore files to place then in `"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool"`?

Currently to access the keystore file with in the resources directory I do:

```
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
Resource resource = appContext.getResource("classpath:com/resources/" +fileName);
((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) appContext).close();
InputStream inpusStream = resource.getInputStream();
KeyStore keyStore = null;
try {
    keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keyStore.load(inpusStream, <Password for JKS file>);
} finally {
    if (inpusStream != null)
        inpusStream.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that you put into src/main/resources gets bundled into the jar, like Andrea suggests.  However, this also means that any time you repackage and deploy your jar you lose any changes made to those files, as you have observed.

If you are running your service on a single host, deploy the java keystore onto the filesystem and inform your java app of its location via a property.  If you plan on deploying it into a cluster, you'll probably want to persist those keys into a database.

Also, just so you know, JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool is a binary used to manage keys and certificates (e.g. use this tool to create a JKS file).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed to know. I ended up going with the filesystem option.

Answer (score 0):

the right place for every resource file is under 'src/main/resources' and then put a resource section in your pom file like this:

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
     ...
```

Comment: So how would you pragmatically get access to the `src/main/resources` directory ?

Comment: This solution wont work, because the keystore file will keep getting reset every time the project is deployed.